# Line break inside round button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a round shaped bordered button using CSS by this:

```
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    border:2px solid #29966c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;           
}
```

and used it in html5 by this:

```
<div align="center">
    <a href="#" class="round-button">
        <font color="#29966c" id="demo"></font>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to create a line break inside the round button,

```
<div align="center"> 
    <a href="#" class="round-button">
         <font color="#29966c" id="demo">hello <br />world</font>
    </a>
</div>
```

So, the "world" comes out of the round button.

[image]

I want both words will be at different line but they both will stay inside the round button window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, `line-height:100px` means each line of text should be 100px tall. That will work to vertically center one line of text (if the container is also 100px tall), but will not work if it is larger than 2 lines of text.

To vertically center the content regardless of how many lines it is, you can use:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PDPTV/

(Note: The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Moving forward, you should use CSS to specify your font colors. The attribute `align=center` is also not supported, so you should use another technique to center your content, but that's for a whole other topic on stack overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

As your `line-height` equals to `width` in your css, the "world" comes out of the round button.
if you set `line-height` to `50px`, you'll get vertically middle aligned text in the button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "line-height:100px;" is pushing the second line down 100px, try this:

```
.round-button{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border:2px solid #29966c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

You may have to fiddle with the height and padding to get the right offset from the top. Remember that the height excludes padding, so subtract the padding from the height.

Answer (score 0):

Your line-height is 100px. do this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/VS7sJ/

```
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:1em;
    border:2px solid #29966c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
span {
    padding:20px 0 0;
    display:block
}
```

`line-height:1em` and wrap the text with `span`

```
<div align="center"> <a href="#" class="round-button"><span><font color="#29966c" id="demo">hello <br />world</font></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its the line height problem. 
because the height is 100px and line-height is also 100 px thats the reason it shows out the button.

```
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:50px;
    border:2px solid #29966c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
```

}

you can also use the given below code to keep the words in center..

```
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    padding-top:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    border:2px solid #29966c;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
```

}